# CLR Trigger Deploy Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, clr

I am attempting to deploy a CLR trigger that links to an external .dll file that contains a library I wrote.  Right now I just want to be able to test the code on a local database.  I have set the local database to Trustworthy = True and external assembly access to my username.  I also added a reference to the external library I am trying to use, but when I call the function I get this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6503, Level 16, 
State 12, Line 1 Assembly 'googlecalendersync, version=1.0.0.0, 
culture=neutral, publickeytoken=fab9d21c96557bef.' was not found in the SQL 
catalog.    Test3   C:\Users\dwd002\Documents\Visual Studio 
2015\Projects\Test3\Test3\bin\Debug\Test3.sql   52
```

Any help would be much apreciated.  I know right now that it is unsafe the way I am doing it, right now it's just a proof of concept.  Is there something I am doing wrong when building the library .dll?

Comment: Can you add that assembly to your database with a `create assembly` statement?

Comment: It turns out that would be the only solution, but since the project consists of 12 or so external dll's adding them would be a pain and the Network Admin doesn't want to change the database to have unsafe code.  Therefor the workaround has been to create all the code I wanted to execute in a c# project and compile that into a .exe, then run that .exe from the trigger.  The c# project will just connect to the database externally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using a 3rd party dll in your clr project

Firstly you need create Assembly From your third party dll

```
use master
GO
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY ClrGoogleCalender
FROM EXECUTABLE FILE='<Your 3rd party dll path>'
CREATE LOGIN CLRGoogleCalenderLOGIN FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY ClrGoogleCalender
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO ClrGoogleCalenderLOGIN
GO
```

And then  Uplaod your third party dll to sql server catalog

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBhQZ.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CuGm.png)